# Failed to compile - Syntax issue while iterating over object

Tags: javascript, syntax, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have a syntax issue that my code editor is unable to compile. I can't seem to know what the issue is exactly. Any help would be much appreciated. This is my code:

```html
   Object.values(otherStatus).map(function(value) {
            for(var i=0; i < otherStatus.length; i++) {
                for(value in otherStatus[i]) {
                    if (otherStatus[i][value].indexOf(Todos) !==-1) {
                        remainingStatus.push(otherStatus[i]);
                    } else if  (otherStatus[i][value].indexOf(Onprogress) !==-1) {
                    remainingStatus.push(otherStatus[i]);
                    } else if (otherStatus[i][value].indexOf(Done) !==-1) {
                        remainingStatus.push(otherStatus[i]);
                    } else {
                        remainingStatus = []
                    }
                } 
            }      
        )};
```

The iteration is within another function that looks like this:

```html
addCardtoApp = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const card = {
            taskName: this.taskName.current.value, 
            taskDescription: this.taskDescription.current.value,
            taskPeriod: this.taskPeriod.current.value,
        };
        const cardStatus = this.taskStatus.current.value;
        let otherStatus = {
            otherStatus: this.taskStatus.current.textContent.replace(`${cardStatus}`, ''),
        };
        let remainingStatus = []
        const Todos = 'Todos'
        const Onprogress = 'Onprogress'
        const Done = 'Done'

        Object.values(otherStatus).map(function(value) {
            for(var i=0; i < otherStatus.length; i++)
                for(value in otherStatus[i]) {
                    if (otherStatus[i][value].indexOf(Todos) !==-1) {
                        remainingStatus.push(otherStatus[i]);
                    } else if  (otherStatus[i][value].indexOf(Onprogress) !==-1) {
                    remainingStatus.push(otherStatus[i]);
                    } else if (otherStatus[i][value].indexOf(Done) !==-1) {
                        remainingStatus.push(otherStatus[i]);
                    } else {
                        remainingStatus = []
                    }
                } 
            }      
        )};
        console.log(remainingStatus)
        this.props.addCard(card, cardStatus, otherStatus);
        event.currentTarget.reset();
        console.log(otherStatus);
    };
```

Comment: In the first code sample, the outer (first) `for` loop is missing `{` at the end of the first line.

Comment: @Pointy I edit the code according to your comment. The code editor still doesn't want to run it.